# Is this structure a Banach bundle?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, vector-bundles, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Put $Y=\{ \phi\in X^{*}\mid\;\; \parallel \phi \parallel\leq 1\;\;  \&\;\; \phi \neq 0\}$ which is  a  locally  compact  Hausdorf space with the weak star topology.

> Is there a well known  Banach bundle structure over $Y$ with the disjoint union of $\ker \phi,\;\phi \in Y$? In particular are all $\ker \phi,\; \phi \in Y$ mutually isomorphic Banach spaces?

Comment: Given a normed vector space, all linear subspaces of the same *finite* co-dimension are mutually isomorphic as normed vector spaces. In your case, $ \ker(\phi) $ has co-dimension $ 1 $ in $ X $ for each $ \phi \in Y $ and is closed in $ X $, hence complete.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Denote by $E$ this family of subspaces. Choose $x\in X$ (with $\|x\|=1$) and $\phi_x\in Y$ with $\phi_x(x)=1$ and consider the weak star open set $U_x=\{\phi\in Y: \phi(x)\ne 0\}$. Then 
$$
E|_{U_x} \ni (y,\phi) \mapsto (y -\phi_x(y).x,\phi)\in \ker(\phi_x)\times U_x
$$
is a trivializing vector bundle chart. The chart changes look like
$$
\ker(\phi_x)\times (U_x\cap U_y)\ni (z,\phi)\mapsto 
\Big(z-\frac{\phi(z)}{\phi(x)}x,\phi\Big)\mapsto
\Big(z-\frac{\phi(z)}{\phi(x)}x - \big(\phi_y(z) - \frac{\phi(z)\phi_y(x)}{\phi(x)}\big)y,\phi\Big)
$$
$$
\in \ker(\phi_y)\times (U_x\cap U_y).
$$
So this is even vector bundle with rational transition functions.

## Edit:

Answers to the questions of the OP.

It is a sub vector bundle of the trivial bundle $X\times Y$ which fixes the topology,

The topology can also be induced by the vector bundle charts. Choosing an abstract linear isomorphism 
from $\ker(\phi_x)$ to to a fixed Banach space (take $\ker(\phi_{x_0})$ for some fixed $x_0$) for every $x$, you may stabilize the fiber and give it a name.

Comment: Prof. Michor, Thank you very much for your answer. To have a Banach bundle,  do not we need to fix(at first) a typical fibre? (I think your fibre depends on x).

Comment: what is the structure and topology of E?

Comment: before trivialization, do not we need to establish  a  family of isomorphisms  $\alpha_{xy}:\ker \phi_{x}\to \ker \phi_{y}$ with cocycle condition? I think your fibers still depends on x. Am I mistaken?

Comment: However a continuous choice of $\phi_{x}$'s is possible but I do not know how we construct the above cocycles (to have a fix fiber)?

Comment: $x$ is just an index, a name for the chart. It is NOT a variable in any chart change, it is a constant!

Comment: your charts $U_{x}$ depends on x and the fiber in this chart is $\ker \phi_{x}$.(as you wrote in the trivializations). So how the structure of fibers are constant?(Please compare with the situation of finite dim vector bundles).

Comment: In order to show what I mean, I ask "when we would decide that this bundle is trivial?"

Comment: The chart changes come from  VB charts (my first display). Use the isomorphism also in the VB charts. So the cocycle conditions are automatic and trivial.

Comment: I think that I can not understand some thing in your answer, or may be something is missing:In your trivialization $$
E|_{U_x} \ni (y,\phi) \mapsto (y -\phi_x(y).x,\phi)\in \ker(\phi_x)\times U_x
$$ you did not use the fact that $(y,\phi)$ is realy  a  member of toatal space of the bundle that is you did not use $\phi(y)=0$.

Comment: So it seems that you are not trivializing the kernel bundle in my question.